In a life-and-death emergency, could an airliner pull away from the gate?
Let's assume that an airliner crew has insider information about the imminent annihilation of the airport where they are currently going through boarding. They need to get away as quickly as possible. It is a regular Airbus or Boeing long-haul.
Assuming that regular airport procedures have come to a stop: At which point would they be able to leave without assistance, under their own power?
For example, normally a passenger jet is pushed back from the gate. Could it back itself out if damage to the terminal etc. didn't matter? The bridge itself is, I think, not really attached to the aircraft, so it shouldn't be a problem.
I think the ground crew usually blocks/wedges the front wheels in to ensure that the aircraft stay in its place. Could those wedges be manually removed by the crew?
Anything I miss that would require specialists or special gear on the ground before an airliner could pull away?

Could someone manually remove a chock? Yes, that's how the ground crew do it...

there's an enjoyable S.King's Langoliers vibe in this one, and a (maybe less enjoyable) Beebo Russell too

@user721108 Re Beebo Russell: Well, the crew is on board, fully professional and capable. And smart. :-).

@Peter-ReinstateMonica imo if one single dude is smart enough, one full crew can do whatever is needed by splitting tasks =)

The timing will be important.  A plane during boarding might not have the engines running and dependant on ground support, so cannot just leave.  Once the engines are started life will be easier to leave.  Engines off it will be more of KYAG.  First is kiss, last is goodbye.

It is much easier for an aircraft with tail mounted engines e.g. MD-80 or modern biz jets. In fact MD-80 was authorized for powerback from the gate

You might be interested in [worldbuilding.se] "Worldbuilding Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for writers, artists and others using science, geography and culture to construct imaginary worlds and settings."

@Jamiec Yes, thanks. I chose to ask here because the question is fairly technical and aviation-specific and (hopefully only with respect to the aviation issues) real-world based. The technical details are not so much related to the story setting.

A case where a main engine was left running during the airport stop: Air Ontario Flight 1363. Discussed in detail here https://youtu.be/a0VPBZbiAdk?si=a8pa6fqZwUT6L-aI&t=2667


Assuming that regular airport procedures have come to a stop: At which point would they be able to leave without assistance, under their own power?

Here are some ideas for a scenario where the ramp personnel is not helping for the departure.
Precompressed air and electric power
In most cases at large airports the aircraft doesn't use its internal APU (a small turbine supplying both compressed air and electric power) to save noise, pollutants and cost.
Instead there are connections to the bridge, to a truck or to the ground. For example the preconditioned air used for air-conditioning flows in these yellow flexible pipes (see @Ralph comment):

Source.
Other connections: Water, wasted water, fuel
There can also be other connections still in place (fuel, water, wasted water). The crew would need to disconnect corresponding pipes and cables; it's possible and that doesn't require any tool.
Here is a typical ramp scene for the A320; vehicles do not come or leave at the same time:

Source: Airbus, Airport and Maintenance Planning.
Everything must and can be disconnected
Everything must be disconnected without damaging the sockets. It would be hazardous to just move the plane until the connections break, e.g. the refueling nozzle would likely stay connected to the wing tank, allowing fuel to leak (see mechanism here); with engines running a fire is almost certain.
The aircraft crew can still go down the ramp using the bridge stairs (below the bridge on the first photo) and disconnect everything.
Ramp obstacles
The crew may also have to move some cart, truck or generator that might be in the way, but that should be manageable.
Open doors, servicing panels, locking devices
There are other points to be considered, like open doors and panels (on engines, on cargo holds, etc), chocks in place, gears moored with mechanical anchors. All of them are manageable without ground support. You can read about these elements on the same linked Airbus document, e.g. the connection points are all described at page 204, and mooring anchors at page 190.
Risks associated with powerback
Using reverse thrust to taxi back is possible but not entirely safe. In normal conditions such operation would have to be validated by the operator and the airport using OpSpec C065.
Taxi and take-off roll times
It can take time to reach the runway, depending on the airport layout. Taxiing faster than the allowed speed is not an option.
It also takes some time to align and accelerate for take-off.

Such departure in a novel would be credible to a pilot, providing the crew takes the related actions.

Great! Also a valuable document in the link.

If we assume the fueling & loading are complete and they're just waiting for a tug to come give them the push-back, how much of that would still be attached? I imagine they'd still be hooked up for external power & air until just about the last minute, but would anything else still be connected at that point?

@DarthPseudonym: When the push-back truck is about to make contact, the APU has been started, the only connection left is the intercom with the wingwalker or the truck driver for a towbarless truck.

"Taxiing at high speed is not an option."  Oh? I can think of a few places (airlines, and airports both) where it's fairly well S.O.P.!  That aside, great answer!

@RalphJ, I agree, that's not what I wanted to say (which was faster than usually).

Detaching comm cords & towbar would be straightforward. Getting out of a towbarless tug would be more involved, if they'd already captured the nosewheel. For storytelling purposes, if the author doesn't want to explain towbarless pushbacks, I'd suggest going with "not hooked up yet" & leave it at that.

One other thought: the air hoses are long & flexible & really, really must be secured, because an engine running at high power can absolutely generate enough suction (wind) to pull a hose right into the motor, and that is a certain way to destroy your engine. Pilots would probably be aware of this, but even in a hurry, that's not a step they can afford to omit. Maybe they could park a baggage cart where it immobilizes the hose... not normal ops, but if in 10 minutes everything is pulverized anyway... why not?

If nuclear war is really on the horizon and the pilots can convince the ground crew of the imminent danger and say "if you get the hoses, etc. removed in the next 2 minutes and climb up the stairs we'll take you with us, if not we'll leave anyway and take our chances with stuff still being connected, I think you might just get the ground crew on board (literally and figuratively).

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact That's a great idea, actually! I'll credit you with it if the story ever gets written :-)

In fact, I think this is very plausible if air raid sirens or the modern equivalent of warnings on everyone's cell phones have just happened and you're near a likely ground zero (e.g., you are on a plane at Reagan Washington National Airport (basically 5 miles to the White House or the US Capitol) - there are reasons for big no-fly zones and crazy takeoff and landing requirements at that airport) there is basically no way you're going to get off the plane and into anything remotely useful as a nuclear bomb shelter in 5 or 10 minutes. But use those few minutes to get off the ground

and head away from the city and you have a chance to survive. Oops. Just reread the question - this would not be "inside information", though perhaps the pilots had a little more advance notice and now everyone knows and panics...

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact going OT here but the idea is that civil aviation comes to a stop due to some elevated alert level (resources and airspace are allocated for military purposes) some time before an actual attack is detected and the general public is alerted.

@Peter But if it's an orderly and timed shutdown, why let people board a plane they aren't going to launch?

The only reasonable scenario I can imagine is fire on the terminal, directly at the other end of the ramp. This means get away quickly; but the airplane doesn't necessarily have to be flightworthy after, just taxi-worthy. Fuel pump will have to be shut down and fuel truck moved, but most pins can get broken.

I simply cannot imagine a scenario in which the "crew has insider information about the imminent annihilation of the airport" and in which disconnecting the bridge, fuel, water, waste and other cables, shutting all the cargo and other doors, removing the chocks, starting the engines and then using reverse thrust to back up onto the taxiway, with a high probability of striking another aircraft, ground vehicle or building, and then presumably taxi to the runway and take off without clearance, or a radio service, or having properly prepared the aircraft would in ANY WAY ever be a better option that simply leaving the aircraft and getting out of there on foot or by other means.
Never say never, but I can't imagine this would ever need to happen in any context.

Thanks for the frame challenge -- I'm trying to prepare a story where an insider has knowledge of an imminent nuclear attack on Germany, including the city they are in (probably Berlin or Frankfurt). Nothing matters except getting the airplane a few km away from ground zero, and then, preferably, on to some suddenly very attractive, poor African country that does not have any oil or other resources needed in a war. That is, damage to structures, violation of procedure, minor damage to the plane  etc. are entirely secondary. Yeah, you should avoid hitting something though, true.

Whether it's possible for the crew to essentially finish ground operation (closing the cargo door, disconnecting anything that absolutely needs to be properly disconnected etc.) are basically the details that I'd like to get some information about. Otherwise the moment of decision would have to be exactly the 5 minutes between pushback and start, which is more unlikely and more contrived.

This does not answer the question and would be better suited as a comment. "That would never happen" isn't a suitable answer to a hypothetical question.

There is a civl war. Ground personnel have already flewn. Happened before.

A similar scenario has actually happened. BA flight 149 from London to Malaysia landed in Kuwait two hours after the start of the Iraqi invasion in 1990. If the captain had been told about the invasion by BA after landing, then an emergency unauthorised departure would have been the correct thing to do. As it was, the crew and passengers were captured by Iraqi forces and used as human shields for several months. I had a friend in the cabin crew.

The crew could simply ask the ground staff (who would be there anyway) to expedite the clearance, but without authorisation, it is very improbable, meaning "crew knowledge" would be insufficient for a fast getaway. A localised event in the terminal - fire, bomb, attack etc, - would be sufficient to encourage the ground crew to expedite departure, or at the very least, separation from the terminal, making a fast departure more possible.

Yes, interaction with the ground staff is also a possible path. (There will likely be some interaction with the tower where the pilot has an acquaintance who ignores some shutdown orders by the military advance command, something along those lines.)


For example, normally a passenger jet is pushed back from the gate. Could it back itself out?

Not really, a jetliner doesn't have a reverse gear 
It must be pushed back by a pushback tug. In the recent past there was the idea of electrifying the nose landing gear to get rid of the pushback tugs and to move the airplane toward the runway without using the engines to save some fuel but I don't know what happened to this idea.
You might resort to use the thrust reversals to "powerback" from the gate: it was used in the past and it's something no more usually done as explained for example here but it can be for sure used in your story.

"When reverse thrust is used to push an aircraft back from the gate, the maneuver is called a powerback"? The reason it's not done is possible damage to near-by structures, I thought.

Actually, the first google hit using the specific keywords (that didn't occur to me before)  is an aviation SE answer! ;-).

Damage to nearby structures is likely to be of lower concern, if you're convinced they are about to be annihilated, I guess.

Furthermore, not all thrust reversers are actually capable of producing reverse thrust at static conditions.  Many would actually be better called 'drag generators' than 'thrust reversers'.  Imagine the flow into the engine.  Most 'reversers' turn the flow.  If they turn the flow up to 90 degrees, the axial component of momentum is reduced (causing drag in forward flight), but not negative thrust at static conditions.  For that, they must turn the flow more than 90 degrees.

Eastern used to power back in the 80's. No tug required.

@RetiredATC AA powerbacked their MD-80s until the early 2000's. Definitely caught your attention in the terminal.
